# UVC_Camera error

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

when i run " roslaunch camera_node launch" it throws following things:

[ WARN ] [1450122956.773110512]: camera calibration file /home/hrishikesh/catkin_ws/src/camera_umd/unv_camera/example.yaml not found.

Setting auto_focus is not supported

Setting focus_absolute is not supported

plz help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/222519/uvc_camera-error/) by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2015-12-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is normal for some cameras. Is the driver publishing images?

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2015-12-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-16**:
no it is not publishing images.But the camera led on laptop does glow but no images are shown.Also all the required topic and nodes do get published.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-16**:
What do you mean by "no images are shown"? Are messages published on the driver's `image_raw` topic?

**Comment by [kaygudo](https://answers.ros.org/users/25082/kaygudo/) on 2015-12-16**:
no image window gets popped and the terminal's last 2 lines  are "Setting auto_focus is not supported

Setting focus_absolute is not supported" .Yup all the required topics and nodes do get shown as mentioned in uvc_camera package.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2015-12-17**:
The uvc driver only publishes image messages; it doesn't open up a window. If you want to view the published images, you should use image_view.